# Debugging the use of std::string in a thread pool C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, segmentation-fault, c++17, threadpool

I'm in the process of trying to figure out multithreading - I'm pretty new to it. I'm using a thread_pool type that I found [here](https://github.com/bshoshany/thread-pool). For sufficiently large `N`, the following code segfaults. Could you guys help me understand why and how to fix?

```
#include "thread_pool.hpp"
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

static std::mutex mtx;
void printString(const std::string &s) {
    std::lock_guard lock(mtx);
    std::hash<std::thread::id> tid{};
    auto id = tid(std::this_thread::get_id()) % 16;
    std::cout << "thread: " << id << " " << s << std::endl;
}

TEST(test, t) {
    thread_pool pool(16);
    int N = 1000000;
    std::vector<std::string> v(N);
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        v[i] = std::to_string(i);
    }
    for (auto &s: v) {
        pool.push_task([&s]() {
            printString(s);
        });
    }

}
```

Here's the thread sanitizer output (note the ===> comments where I direct you to appropriate line"):

```
SEGV on unknown address 0x000117fbdee8 (pc 0x000102fa35b6 bp 0x7e8000186b50 sp 0x7e8000186b30 T257195)
0x102fa35b6 std::basic_string::__get_short_size const string:1514 
0x102fa3321 std::basic_string::size const string:970 
0x102f939e6 std::operator<<<…> ostream:1056 
0x102f9380b printString RoadRunnerMapTests.cpp:37   // ==> this line: void printString(const std::string &s) {
0x102fabbd5 $_0::operator() const RoadRunnerMapTests.cpp:49     // ===> this line: v[i] = std::to_string(i);
0x102fabb3d (test_cxx_api_RoadRunnerMapTests:x86_64+0x10001eb3d) type_traits:3694 
0x102fabaad std::__invoke_void_return_wrapper::__call<…> __functional_base:348 
0x102faba5d std::__function::__alloc_func::operator() functional:1558 
0x102fa9669 std::__function::__func::operator() functional:1732 
0x102f9d383 std::__function::__value_func::operator() const functional:1885 
0x102f9c055 std::function::operator() const functional:2560 
0x102f9bc29 thread_pool::worker thread_pool.hpp:389  // ==> [this](https://github.com/bshoshany/thread-pool/blob/master/thread_pool.hpp#L389) line
0x102fa00bc (test_cxx_api_RoadRunnerMapTests:x86_64+0x1000130bc) type_traits:3635 
0x102f9ff1e std::__thread_execute<…> thread:286 
0x102f9f005 std::__thread_proxy<…> thread:297 
0x1033e9a2c __tsan_thread_start_func 
0x7fff204828fb _pthread_start 
0x7fff2047e442 thread_start
```

Comment: Does it happen for `N > 16` perhaps? In any case, extract a [mcve]!

Comment: Maybe not related to your bug, but why create the vector, `v`? Why two loops in the `TEST` function? Why not just one loop that creates each string, and then immediately pushes the task that deals with that string?

Comment: Also, maybe not related to your bug, but why create a thread pool that has 16 worker threads when the `mtx` mutex prevents any more than one of them doing any work at any moment in time?

Comment: This code is literally just trying to reproduce my actual bug (which is why this is a MWE). N > 16 is a interesting suggestion. I'll investigate. Also, I don't care about actual speed up, hence the linear 'setup' loop followed by the thread pool.

Comment: Also, the 16 worker threads plus mutex is literally me flailing around with multithreading. I'll get there ;)

Comment: And thank you all for your answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Destructors are called in the order opposite to variable declaration order. i.e. `v` will be destructed earlier than `pool`, therefore at the moment when some threads from pool will call to `printString()`, the argument string will not be a valid object, because `v` and its content are already destroyed. To resolve this, I'd recommend to declare `v` before `pool`.

Comment: Brilliant, I totally overlooked this. I could also make sure the main thread waits for all the worker threads to finish before exiting the function using `pool.wait_for_tasks();`

Answer (score 1):

Tasks passed to thread pool contain references to content of vector `v`, however this vector goes out of scope prior to pool leaving tasks with dangling references. In order to fix this you need to reorder scopes of variables:

```
int N = 1000000;
std::vector<std::string> v(N);
thread_pool pool(16);
```